# Mapping a function over two input lists

Tags: haskell

I have a function that I want to test with several sets of inputs. Let's say the function is

```
f :: a -> b -> c
```

Now I have two lists of inputs:

```
inputA :: [a]
inputB :: [[b]]
```

For `inputA !! i`, I want evaluate `f $ input !! i` for each element of the list at `inputB !! i`. I know I need several applications of `map` to do this, but I am having difficulty wrapping my head around a solution.

My most recent attempt is

```
map f inputA <$> inputB
```

which gives the following error:

> Couldn't match expected type `a0 -> b0' with actual type`[b1]'
>       In the return type of a call of `map'
>
>       Probable cause:`map' is applied to too many arguments
>       In the first argument of `(<$>)', namely`map f inputA'
>       In the expression: map f inputA  inputB

How should I go about solving this problem? I don't necessarily want a complete solution. A push (or even a shove) in a helpful direction would definitely be appreciated.

**Additional thoughts:**

```
map f inputA :: [b -> c]
```

I think this is the right direction. Now I need to map each of the functions over each list of inputs in `inputB`.

To clarify, I want to map the `i`th function in `map f inputA` over the `i`th list of inputs in `inputB` to get a result `outputC :: [[c]]`.

Comment: In case you haven't seen it yet, you might also be interested in [QuickCheck](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck).

Comment: @DanielWagner Thanks for the link. I have read about QuickCheck very briefly and it is on my List of Things to Learn About Haskell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, something like:

```hs
mapNested :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [[b]] -> [[c]]
mapNested f [] _ = []
mapNested f _ [] = []
mapNested f (x:xs) ys = concatMap (map (f x)) ys : mapNested f xs ys

Main> mapNested (+) [1, 2, 3] [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
[[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],[3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11],[4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]]
```

If this isn't what you're looking for, could you provide an example input and output?

**EDIT**

Or is this what you're wanting?

```hs
mapNested :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [[b]] -> [[c]]
mapNested f xs = zipWith map (map f xs)

Main> mapNested (,) [1, 2, 3] [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
[[(1,1),(1,2),(1,3)],[(2,4),(2,5),(2,6)],[(3,7),(3,8),(3,9)]]
```

Comment: This is almost what I'm going for. However, using your example, I want to add 1 to the elements of the first list, 2 to the second list, and 3 to the third list rather than adding each number to all of elements of every list.

Comment: You get the check mark for being the first to answer. After seeing your use of `zipWith`, it seems quite obvious (especially since I am already using `zipWith` in several other related contexts).

Answer (score 6):

You can use `zipWith`

```
Prelude> let a = [1,2,3]
Prelude> let b = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
Prelude> zipWith (\a' bl -> map (+a') bl)  a b
[[2,3,4],[6,7,8],[10,11,12]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Everything is easy with list comprehensions,

```
g f xs yss = [ [f x y | y <- ys] | (x,ys) <- zip xs yss]
           = [ map    (f x)  ys  | (x,ys) <- zip xs yss]
           = [ map     fx    ys  | (fx,ys) <- zip (map f xs) yss]
           = zipWith map (map f xs) yss

           = [ (map . f) x   ys  | (x,ys) <- zip xs yss]
           = zipWith (map . f) xs yss
```

the last one first shown by [@nponeccop](https://stackoverflow.com/users/805266/nponeccop) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19194396/mapping-a-function-over-two-input-lists/19196862#comment28402653_19194858), and also hinted at in other answers; we can get it from them by using code transformations

```
map c' $ zip a b     == zipWith c a b   where  c' (a,b) = c a b
map (c a) b          == (map . c) a b
\ a b -> map (c a) b ==  map . c
```

It seems you've tried to find a pointfree version of it, too:

```
           = zipWith (map . f) xs yss
           = (zipWith . (map .)) f xs yss
```

so by eta-reduction `g = (zipWith . (map .))` but this might not be easily comprehensible. This is further obfuscated as `zipWith <$> (map <$>)` and even `zipWith <$> ((<$>) <$>)`.

Or, we can use [the `ZipList` type from `Control.Applicative`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Control-Applicative.html#t:ZipList) as

```
           = zipWith (map . f) xs yss
           = getZipList $ liftA2 (map . f)    (ZipList xs)    (ZipList yss)
           = getZipList $ pure   (map . f) <*> ZipList xs  <*> ZipList yss
           = getZipList $        (map . f) <$> ZipList xs  <*> ZipList yss
           = getZipList $       map <$> (f <$> ZipList xs) <*> ZipList yss
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, this is what you need:

```
Prelude> let f x y = x + y
Prelude> let xs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
Prelude> let ys = [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7], [8], [9, 10]]
Prelude> map (\(x, ys) -> map (f x) ys) $ zip xs ys
[[2,3],[5,6,7],[9,10],[12],[14,15]]
Prelude>
```

i.e.

```
fancyZipMap :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [[b]] -> [[c]]
fancyZipMap f xs yys = map (\(x, ys) -> map (f x) ys) $ zip xs yys
```

Comment: A shorter version: `fancyZipMap f = zipWith $ map . f`