# Writing a custom map function

Tags: haskell, monads

Now there might be something in the Haskell Libraries to do what I want. I'm enough of a noob to not know any better and I'm trying to write a custom map function using the tools that I know. The type signature needs to be

```
myMap :: (Monad m) => (a -> b) -> [m a] -> [m b]
```

where `myMap f as` returns a list after applying `f` to each of the value in each Monad in `as`.

My first attempt was

```
myMap f = map (\x x >>= f)
```

However, this has a type signature of

```
myMap :: (Monad m) => (a -> m b) -> [m a] -> [m b]
```

This is so close to what I need, I can scream. Now I need some tips of how to continue from here. I really hope it is as easy as a library function, but I'm willing to write my own short function to do this instead.

Related Question:

[Mapping a function over two input lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19194396/mapping-a-function-over-two-input-lists)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you could turn your `(a -> b)` function in to `m a -> m b` then you could use `map` itself.  So, what do you need to do this?  Hoogle is quite good for this sort of thing.  Doing a search for `(a -> b) -> (m a -> m b)` gives these results:

http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28a+-%3E+b%29+-%3E+%28m+a+-%3E+m+b%29

Near the top are `fmap` (which use `Functor`) and `liftM` (which use `Monad`).  Either would do, but you're using monads, so let's go with `liftM`.  Thus:

```
myMap :: Monad m => (a -> b) -> [m a] -> [m b]
myMap f = map (liftM f)
```

Comment: And that can be eta reduced.

Comment: Looks like `liftM` is the library function I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You were almost there in your attempt, what you were missing was `return`:

```
myMap :: (Monad m) => (a -> b) -> [m a] -> [m b]
myMap f = map $ flip (>>=) $ return . f
```

Basically you needed a way to

- unwrap `a` from `m a` - we use `>>=` for that
- apply `f` to it
- wrap `f` return value in `m` to get `m b` - we use `return` for that