# Custom map function: mapLift

Tags: haskell, monads

After discussing my current issue at [Writing a custom map function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19216243/writing-a-custom-map-function), I thought I found a solution to my problem:

```
mapLift :: Monad m => (a -> b) -> [m a] -> [m b]
mapLift f = map (liftM f)
```

However, when I use it, I get a compiler error. My actual code is:

```
actuals     = zipWith mapLift (mapLift eval wffs) assignments
```

where

```
eval :: Wff -> Assignment -> Maybe Bool
wffs :: [Either String Wff]
assignments :: [Assignment]
```

This code gives the following error message:

> ```
> Couldn't match expected type `a0 -> Wff'
>             with actual type `Either String Wff'
> Expected type: [a0 -> Wff]
>   Actual type: [Either String Wff]
> In the second argument of `mapLift', namely `wffs'
> In the second argument of `zipWith', namely `(mapLift eval wffs)'
> ```

What am I doing wrong? I want to map `eval` over `wffs` while preserving any `Left`s which give error messages from a previous step in the process.

**Edit:**

Originally, my idea was that `actuals :: [Either String (Maybe Bool)]`. However, I am considering modifying `eval` to be `eval :: Wff -> Assignment -> Either String Bool` instead, so that `actuals :: [Either String Bool]`.

**Update:**

I made a typo in my original question. `assignments` should be:

```
assignments :: [[Assignment]]
```

Comment: Can you add the type of result you want?

Comment: Just to clarify, are the types `Assignment` and `Assignments` supposed to be the same?

Comment: @Fixnum Yes they are. I have fixed that typo as well.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not exactly sure what you want the type of `actuals` to be, but let's assume it's `[Either String (Maybe Bool)]`.  In that case, let's start with

```
actuals = zipWith (\ew a -> undefined) wffs assignments
```

where `ew` is an `Either String Wff` and `a` is an `Assignment`.  What should the body of our function be?  Somehow, we need to lift `eval` into the `Either`.  If the Assignment were in `Either` as well, we could write `liftM2 eval a ew` - but it's not. So, we can either use a `return a` here, or apply `eval` to its `Assignment` argument first with `flip`, and then lift it (or many other possibilities):

```
actuals = zipWith (\ew a -> liftM (flip eval a) ew) wffs assignments
```

Optionally, let's golf further:

```
actuals = zipWith (\ew -> flip liftM ew . flip eval) wffs assignments
```

In my opinion, neither is as clear as

```
\ew a -> eval <$> ew <*> return a
```

where `<$>` is another name for `liftM` from `Control.Applicative`.  You can learn more about `<$>` and `<*>` in, e.g., "Learn you a Haskell", but basically `f <$> ma <*> mb <*> ... <*> mn` (equivalently `liftMn f ma mb ... mn` for small enough `n`) is the monadic (actually, `applicative`) version of `f a ... n`.

At this point you could extract all the failures or whatever.  I wonder if the presence of the `Maybe` and the `Either` is a sign you could simplify your types slightly.  For instance, if your `eval` could fail to evaluate a Wff, you could use an `Either` instead of `Maybe` to record the error.  Then, errors will be caught at the step in which they occur, and successes will propagate in the usual way of the `Either` monad:

```
-- eval :: Wff -> Assignment -> Either String Bool
actuals :: [Either String Bool]
actuals  = zipWith (\ew a -> ew >>= flip eval a) wffs assignments
```

See also the [`errors`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/errors) package, which provides - among its many salutatory features - some helpful combinators to go between `Either` and `Maybe`.

I didn't solve the problem in the way you proposed, which was to map over the first list before zipping. But you can do that too, of course:

```
actuals  = zipWith (\ef a -> liftM ($ a) ef) (mapLift eval wffs) assignments
```

Here `liftM ($ a)` is a mildly clever alternative to `ef <*> return a`.

This seems a bit noisier - `zipWith` is already a sort of map, a fact you may as well take advantage of.

EDIT in response to OP's edits: If you want `actuals :: [[Assignment]]` then the needed changes are simple:

```
actuals :: [Either String (Maybe Bool)]
actuals = 
  concat $ zipWith (\ew -> map (liftA2 eval ew . return)) wffs assignments
```

The idea here is I again started with something of the form `concat $ zipWith f wffs assignments` for unknown `f` (the `concat` is because the `[[]]` type needs to be flattened somehow ... if you forgot it, the types wouldn't quite match), and then queried the compiler for the type of `f` (via writing `where f :: (); f = undefined` and examining the resulting error message), then wrote the appropriate function, then eta-reduced (golfed).  GHC 7.8 will have type holes, allowing you to get the type of an undefined, still-to-be written expression, enabling a much more elegant way of Type-Driven Development (TDD) than is possible today (except in, e.g., Agda).

Adapting this to use list comprehensions and to have type `[Either String Bool]`, as per my original post, is left as a useful exercise :)

Comment: "where `<$>` is another name for `liftM`" My understanding is that `<$> = fmap`. Does that mean `liftM = fmap` as well?

Comment: The `Either` is because of a possible error when parsing a `String` to create a `Wff`. I haven't gone as far to do the same for `eval`, because there is only one reason for an error: a missing assignment for a variable. It would probably be helpful to have an error message for the specific variable which is missing.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I will definitely need some time to digest it.

Comment: @Code-Guru Yes, all `liftM#` functions are the same as the `liftA#` functions, and more specifically `liftA` without any number is the same thing as `fmap`. `liftA#` with numbers can be replaced with a combination of `fmap` and `ap`. If you use the infix symbols for this, `<$>` and `<*>` respectively, it is called using an "applicative style."

Comment: I made a typo in my original question. Please see the update.

Answer (score 2):

`mapLift`'s first argument is a function from `a -> b`. You pass as a first argument `eval :: Wff -> Assignment -> Maybe Bool`. Due to associativity of `(->)` that means that `a` unifies with `Wff` and `b` with `Assignment -> Maybe Bool`. That means that the next argument to `mapLift`, `wffs` is anticipated to have the type `[m Wff]` which lets `m` unify with `Either String`. That's all fine.

The problem is that the result `mapLift eval wffs` will end up with type `[m b]` which, given what `m` and `b` unified to is `[Either String (Assignment -> Maybe Bool)]`. This is going south already, but let's continue to follow it.

`zipWith` has type `(a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]` and we pass the first argument to it as `mapLift :: (s -> t) -> [m s] -> [m t]`. This means that `zipWith` ends up unifying `a` with the function type `(s -> t)`, `b` with `[m s]` and `[c]` with `[m t]` such that

```
zipWith mapLift :: [s -> t] -> [[m s]] -> [[m t]]
```

Now let's pass in the result `(mapLift eval wffs)` and watch the fireworks.

```
zipWith mapLift :: [s -> t] -> [[m s]] -> [[m t]]
                (mapLift eval wffs) :: [Either String (Assignment -> Maybe Bool)]
```

In order to proceed the typechecker must unify `[s -> t]` with `[Either String (Assignment -> Maybe Bool)]`. The outer `[]` is dispatch immediately, but we still need to find a way to show `s -> t   ~   Either String (Assignment -> Maybe Bool)` which is just impossible due to the wrapping `Either String`.

---

The problem is that your types don't line up because your semantics are missing a way of unifying the two kinds of failure---the `Either String` and the `Maybe`. Fortunately, this is doable by unpacking the `Either` into functions which take an `Assignment`. Here's one way

```
fixEither :: Either String (Assignment -> Maybe Bool) -> (Assignment -> Maybe Bool)
fixEither (Left _)  _ = Nothing
fixEither (Right f) a = f a
```

---

Now finally, if we were to try running

```
zipWith mapLift (map fixEither $ mapLift eval wffs) assignments
```

there'd still be a problem as

```
zipWith mapLift (map fixEither $ mapLift eval wffs)
  :: [[m Assignments]] -> [[m (Maybe Bool)]]
```

while `assignments :: [Assignments]` won't match. We need to wrap `assignments` in at least another layer of `[]` and some `m`. Furthermore, it's not clear what `m` you want.

---

What this means is you probably haven't defined your algorithm well enough yet.

I would always recommend doing a recursive algorithm or one that uses just "plain" `map` first to test that you understand completely how the various layers of lists and functions and monads interleave. The shortcuts afforded by `fmap` and `liftM` are very powerful but take some time to get right.

Comment: `mapLift zipWith` should be `zipWith mapLift`. Does this change your analysis?

Comment: +1 For telling me to back up a step and do it by hand. I have to constantly tell my math students not to do too much in their heads. It's nice to be reminded of that myself.

Comment: Oh, no, that was my own typo. In my head I was writing `zipWith mapLift`. And I'm simply a huge proponent of stepping through type inference to see how all the pieces work. It can be rather mysterious since a lot of things go on behind the scenes, but each step ends up being fairly simple.

Comment: I made a typo in my original question. Please see the update.

Answer (score 2):

`fmap` or `<$>` is enough for this case (assuming the output you want is of type `[Either String (Maybe Bool)]`:

```
result :: [Either String (Maybe Bool)]
result =  zipWith (<$>) [flip eval $ a | a <- assignments]  wffs
```

Comment: Yes, this is the type that I had in mind. I think using a list comprehension makes this more clear than an equivalent solutions using function composition or `map`.

Comment: This solution is short and simple. However, I made a typo in my original question. Please see the update.